# Magento 2.2.5 Question about permissions - checkout infinite loop

Tags: magento2.2, onepage-checkout, permissions, onestepcheckout

Currently I am in developer mode and I think I am having a problem with permissions. I am only using a magento user to run magento tasks and never sudo/root.

I have seen that the files that get deployed via `setup:static-content:deploy` are set to `www-data:www-data` instead of `magento:www-data`

[image]

Is this normal? The reason this got my attention was that by using a module (one-step-checkout) I was having an infinite loading loop in the checkout. And by inspecting the elements of the page I could see that I couldn't load a `js` file.

[image]

So, I thought that it was a file/folder permission problem.